# Input returning wrong result when i dont assign it a name

Tags: python

I'm trying to do

```
answers =["A", "B", "C"]
def result():
    if input == (answers[0]):
        print("Correct")
    else:
        print("Wrong")
input("What is the answer")
result()
```

but when I run this it always returns "Wrong" no matter what i put in.

I kinda figured out that if I assign a name to the input then it will print the right thing but i dont know how to write that in my function as I want to have multiple questions.

Is there a way to fix this or do I just have to write it out manually after every question?

Answer (score 3):

`input` is a function.  So this is wrong:

```
if input == (answers[0]):
```

You're comparing the function (not the return value from a call to the function).

You need to capture the result of calling `input()`, then pass that value to your correctness/scoring function.

Answer (score 0):

```
answers = ["A", "B", "C"]
def result():
    if input("What is the answer ") == (answers[0]):
        print("Correct")
    else:
        print("Wrong")

result()
```

Instead of calling function outside you can simply call it before comparison with answers[0], If you try to use input outside then your have to assign it with a variable.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tysvx.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you check types of two operands in the `if` then you will understand your mistake :

```
In [1]: type(input)
Out[1]: builtin_function_or_method   # Note this
```

And

```
In [2]: answers = ["A", "B", "C"]
In [3]: type(answers[0])
Out[3]: str                          # Note this
```

Thus you are comparing a `function` with a `string`, which is like comparing oranges with lemons.